# adding numpy vector to a numpy multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, numpy, slice

I have a loop that adds elements to a 1d array:

```
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        fvector[0, i] = function_value
```

after the loop finishes, I have a 1 x 1000 vector that I want to store in a multi-dimensional array fmatrix, which is 50 x 1000. I managed to do this using a loop and copying each element individually - but it is very slow. I've then tried to use slice to copy the whole vector in one go after the loop and then be ready to copy next vector at the next column. How do I make it go to the next column? I've tried:

```
    s=slice([i], None)
    fmatrix[s] = fvector
```

and various combinations for s, but I get error messages about setting an array element with a sequence, or invalid syntax.

I know this should be straight forward but I'm very new to python, numpy and arrays :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Allocate the matrix, here zero-initialized for effect:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> fmatrix = np.zeros((50, 1000))
```

Then index into it to obtain `fvector`:

```
>>> fvector = fmatrix[0]
```

Then assign to `fvector`'s elements:

```
>>> for i in xrange(1000):
...     fvector[i] = i
```

If you now inspect `fmatrix[0]`, the first row of `fmatrix`, you'll find that it has been assigned to in the previous loop. That's because the NumPy row indexing creates `fvector` as a *view* on `fmatrix`'s first row. This saves you a copy.

Comment: How do I move onto fmatrix[1] and then all the way to the last row without getting an 'index out of bounds error?

Comment: @wot: you can loop over the rows with `for fvector in fmatrix`; no need for indexing.

Answer (score 1):

`fvector` has shape (1,1000). That's a 2D array, even if one axis has length 1.
You can slice it down to a 1D array with `fvector[0,:]`. This gives the first row.

`fmatrix` has shape (50,1000). You can slice it down to a 1D array with `fmatrix[i,:]`. This gives the `i`th row.

So to assign the values in the first row of `fvector` to the `i`th row of `fmatrix`:

```
fmatrix[i,:] = fvector[0,:]
```

---

Perhaps however there is no need for `fvector` to be a 2D array? Perhaps just make it a 1D array to begin with:

```
fvector = np.empty(1000)
for i in range(0, 1000):
    fvector[i] = function_value
```

and then you could do the assignment with

```
fmatrix[i,:] = fvector
```

Comment: Thanks - I realise my confusion about 1d - 2d arrays is probably causing problems elsewhere too.

Comment: I went back and changed my 2D arrays to 1D and that really helped with the assignment syntax. I used larsmans 'view' feature for populating the matrix. So huge thanks to both.